# qmake generated target_wrapper.sh fails on make check

Tags: bash, qt, qmake, mingw-w64, qtestlib

I have a qmake project with a subdirs template and two child projects.
The subdir projects are two testcases. The project is built with on mingw64.

When I run "mingw32-make check", the process fails when the first testcase is called by the target_wrapper.sh:

```
cd && /C/JENKINS/workspace/MyProject/tests/test1/target_wrapper.sh release/test1.exe
/C/JENKINS/workspace/MyProject/tests/test1/target_wrapper.sh: Zeile 6: /home/jenluelokal/release/test1.exe: No such file or directory
mingw32-make[2]: *** [Makefile.Release:82: check] Error 127
```

The Makefile.Release calls the following line for the check target:

```
check: first
    cd && /C/JENKINS/workspace/MyProject/tests/test1/target_wrapper.sh $(TESTRUNNER) release/$(TARGET) $(TESTARGS)
```

**By request the target_wrapper.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/C/Qt/Qt5.9.2/5.9/mingw64/bin:$PATH
export PATH
QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/C/Qt/Qt5.9.2/5.9/mingw64/share/qt5/plugins${QT_PLUGIN_PATH:+:$QT_PLUGIN_PATH}
export QT_PLUGIN_PATH
exec "$@"
```

The first cd changes into the homedir of the current user and calls target_wrapper.sh. The target_wrapper.sh script tries to execute the
test1 binary - which is not inside the home directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the target_wrapper.sh.

Comment: Added the target_wrapper.sh to my question.

Comment: Did you add `DESTDIR = ...` to your .pro-file?

Comment: No. The test programs are not installed or deployed.

Comment: Thats why it says `/home/jenluelokal/release/test1.exe: No such file or directory` its not there. Set  `DESTDIR =  /home/jenluelokal/release`. Also your paths are looking like you mix Windows with Linux.

Comment: The testsystem is a Windows 7 Machine with a Qt5 compiled for Mingw64. The build script is a short bash script running inside the msys/mingw environment. No linux involved, just a GNU-style toolchain. I don't see the need to copy the test programs into my homedirectory before I can run "make check".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DESTDIR needs be set, so the make check target knows where to look for the test executables. The "cd" changes into this directory before trying to run the target_wrapper.sh.